# Return 2 values using array_map()

Tags: php, mysql

In my code, I get 1 return `$subTotal = array_map(function($item))` to return the all the `product_price`. I want to return one more value `$subWeight` in the same `array_map`. How can I work with this?

[image]

```
<?php foreach ($product->getData('orders') as $item) :
    $cart = $product->getProduct($item['product_ID']);
    $subTotal[]= array_map(function ($item){
    ?>

    <!-- cart item -->
    <div class="row border-top py-3 mt-3">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="<?php echo $item['product_imagename']?>" style="height: 120px;" alt="cart1" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h5 class="font-baloo font-size-20 mb-2"><?php echo $item['product_name']?></h5>
            <h6 class="font-baloo font-size-20 mb-2"><?php echo $item['product_weight']?> lbs</h6>

            <!-- product qty -->
            <div class="qty d-flex pt-2">
                <div class="d-flex font-rale w-25">
                    <button class="qty-up border bg-light" data-id="<?php echo $item['product_ID'] ?? '0'; ?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></button>
                    <input type="text" data-id="<?php echo $item['product_ID'] ?? '0'; ?>" class="qty_input border px-2 w-100 bg-light" disabled value="1" placeholder="1">
                    <button data-id="<?php echo $item['product_ID'] ?? '0'; ?>" class="qty-down border bg-light"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                </div>

                <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['product_ID'] ?? 0; ?>" name="product_ID">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete-cart-submit" class="buttons">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- !product qty -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
            <div class="font-size-20 text-danger font-baloo">
                $<span class="product_price" data-id="<?php echo $item['product_ID'] ?? '0'; ?>"><?php echo $item['product_price'] ?? 0; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- !cart item -->
    <?php
    return $item['product_price'];
}, $cart); // closing array_map function
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here instead of sharing a screenshot of your code. Thanks

Comment: hi ! I just posted my code. Thank you very much

Comment: That is a pretty *huge* amount of stuff to map. Are you sure this is the best approach? A simpler design where you map the data, then later expand it into that sort of form inside a simple `foreach` type loop.